# Common ASP.NET Intermittent Hang-Ups

Tags: asp.net, iis, session, application-pool, inproc

Recently, we've encountered some strange intermittent issues in our ASP.NET app.  These issues would include:

- Static Variables becoming un-initialized
- Background threads aborting
- (InProc) session state being lost

The weird thing was, these issues occurred about every 30 hours. "Weird," we thought...

Well, I'm sure some of you are thinking, "Sounds like an App Pool Recycle Property to me."  You're right.  Our app pool was set to the default of 1740 minutes before it would automatically recycle causing us to lose our state, statics, etc.

So my point is this, there are some things in IIS, ASP.NET, whatever which can cause intermittent hang-ups.  What are some of the things you've ran into?

To start off,

Modifying a web.config file can cause the app to restart which will cause all sessions to end (when you use the InProc mode).

Many Thanks,

Comment: We once had some problems with intermittent hangs because of poorly coded database connections in ASP and ASP.NET applications and them not being disposed of correctly.  It was notoriously difficult to track some of these down however...

Answer (score 2):

You may also want to consider the possibility that the w3wp.exe process that asp.net runs in may be crashing due to an unhandled exception related to the framework. If this is part of the problem, you'll find entries in the system and application event log on the culprit server that specifically indicate a w3wp.exe processing being halted. The problem is that it won't tell you why. It will only record that something caused it to stop functioning.

To alleviate the symptoms, you can begin by decoupling your session from the w3wp.exe process by changing InProc to a state server (either local or sql). Session will then no longer be lost if this process crashes, but it'll be restored to memory at the first opportunity. You can also change the settings in your application pool to recycle at a different rate. If w3wp.exe is crashing, you'll likely need to recycle much more rapidly and possible remove "Enable fail protection".

All of that just masks the problem though. In order to isolate a problem of this nature, you'll need to install and run the [IIS Debug Diagnostic Tool](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=28bd5941-c458-46f1-b24d-f60151d875a3&DisplayLang=en). Its crash/hang reports are very informative, and absolutely crucial in finding the problems that occur in the murky space between Asp.Net and IIS.

Answer (score 0):

Just for session troubleshooting, this one should suffice... http://aspalliance.com/1182

Hangs on the other hand can happen due to many other reasons. Best way of fixing such issues is to use any tool like windbg or Debug Diagnostics to create dumps when the issue is happening and create memory dumps. Later these memory dumps can be analyzed for issues.

http://blogs.msdn.com/tess has many posts about debugging various scenarios.